# Prove that for positive integer n we have $(2^n-1)^2 \mid 2^{n(2^n-1)} - 1$.

Tags: number-theory

How to solve this?

$$(2^n-1)^2 \mid 2^{n(2^n-1)} - 1$$

Comment: Where did you get that problem from?

Comment: My teacher gave me this problem

Comment: (2^n−1)^2∣((2^n-1)+1)^(2n−1)−1

Comment: Maybe for all positive x we have x^2|(x+1)^x-1

Comment: UUhhh, in this situation, what does | mean??

Comment: @simplest_mathematics It's a standard notation for "divides".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The expression $$\dfrac{(x+1)^x-1}{x^2}$$ is an integer for all positive integers $x$. We have $$(x+1)^x-1 = x^x+\binom{x}{1}x^{x-1}+\cdots+\binom{x}{x-1}x+1-1 \equiv 0 \pmod{x^2}.$$